# Center Image at the bottom of a div with a viewport height on it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an image to sit at the bottom of a div. The div has a viewport height of 100 but also a minimum height of 680px. The image sits nicely at the bottom until I begin to scroll down the page and the viewport height is smaller than 680px.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="arrow">
           <img src="arrow.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-color: #29a9e2;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 680px;
    background-size: cover;}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0px auto;}

.arrow {
    /* this is just what i've been experimenting with*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 600px;}
```

Here's a Fiddle that show kind of what my problem is. https://jsfiddle.net/u7b95fve/

(Make the viewport smaller than 680px and then scroll down).
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `position:relative` to the styles for `<header>`.

Then the `position:absolute` for `.arrow` will work properly.

**Reason:** If you want to position an element absolutely within another element, you must *explicitly* declare positioning for the parent element.

Comment: Yep, perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Have one more question for you. Even though I have the minimum height of the div set to 680 px it seems that the text overflows the viewport height probably because of its size. Is there a way of increasing that height again if the text overflows or should I just use FitText.

Comment: One possible solution might be to use `overflow-y:auto` - this will add a vertical scrollbar to the `<header>` if the height of the text exceeds the available vertical space. However, the most common approach to ensuring the height of the parent expands to account for the height of the text is by deploying `height:auto;` ... which isn't really what you want if you're declaring `min-height:680px;`